# как отправить запрос с nginx на сервер через http proxy?

Tags: nginx, https, proxy

Нужно отправлять запросы приходящие на nginx (версия 0.18 ubuntu 20.04) через http proxy по https, как я понимаю метод CONNECT.
Перечитал доку, перепробовал разные решения, никак не получается.
Нашел модуль который включает поддержку "прокси протокола" для входящих соединений на nginx, но мне нужно на исходящий.

```
location /toserver/ {
    proxy_method CONNECT;
    proxy_set_header Host other.server:443;
    proxy_pass http://proxy.server.com:3128;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно какую задачу вы хотите решить? Может вам нужен не nginx?

Comment: Про задачу, не хочу распространятся, да она специфическая. Эту задачу, можно решить отправляя запросы на бекенд и там уже в прокси, но это накладно, пытаюсь уменьшить потребление ресурсов. Пробую nginx-lua.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803431/4827341